# Redis save old keys to a file

Tags: redis

In my redis configuration I have a lot of keys, however only few of them are being frequently updated.

Is there a way for redis to save rarely-used keys to file so that they will not occupy ram, but would be loaded if called via `get`?

Answer (score 0):

No, Redis doesn't offer that. There are reports, however, of people getting decent results just by using the OS' virtual memory.

See [Redis virtual memory](http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory) and [Redis virtual memory internals](http://redis.io/topics/internals-vm)